# Hierarchical data in MongoDB?

Tags: mysql, mongodb, hierarchy

I have a question regarding Hierarchical data.

Our app shows posts, that are structured inside parents. Here's how it goes:

`prof->sprof->subject->post`

(Each `prof` can contain multiple `sprof`s, and each `sprof` can contain multiple `subject`s, and each `subject` contains multiple `post`s)

Right now, we've set up a temporary MySQL Database that looks like this:

There are 4 tables: `profs`, `sprofs`, `subjects` and `posts`. Inside the table `profs` you have a row for each `prof` - and each `prof` has it's unique ID.

Inside the table `sprofs`, each `sprof` has it's own unique ID, but **It also has a field for the ID of its parent.** For example, if there's a `prof` with the ID 1, a `sprof` might have a `parent_id` of 1 (to indicate that its prof (its parent) is `prof` number 1).

And so on - each `subject` has a field for its `sprof`'s ID, and each `post` has a field for its `subject`'s ID.

So for example, if we want to get all the posts under the `subject` number 2, we do:

`SELECT * FROM 'posts' WHERE 'subject_id'=2`

A friend told me, that *MongoDB* can have structured data, so for example I could put a "table" of "posts" under a "row" inside the "table" of "subjects".

Is it true? Will it help? Will it be faster than using MySQL?

I'm not familliar with MongoDB at all, but I'd like to learn that anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question to answer first is, are any of the possible children bounded or unbounded sets of data? The next question is, how are you going to be requesting the data? Another question would be, how often will the data be written?

One of the things you'll learn quickly with MongoDB is the answer to any schema questions is almost always "It depends". It depends on the answers to the questions I asked above and a few more. To get you on your way though, MongoDB has [some great documentation on the subject of hierarchies](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/model-tree-structures/). This gets you part of the way to your solution.

Then you have to understand your data access patterns and when to normalize or denormalize data. Something to help you make that decision can be read [in this great blog](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/87200945828/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-1).

Sorry to leave you with a not so cut and dry answer. Yes, MongoDB can take care of hierarchical data. How should it be done? It depends. Will it be faster than MySQL, it depends. Can it be faster than MySQL? Most definitely.

Scott

Comment: This doesn't really give an answer.

Answer (score -1):

That's true. You can put hierarchical data in MongoDB. But I think you could perfectly fit what you got in one MySQL table?

Let's say structure would look like

```
ID  ParentID    TypeID  Value
1   NULL        1       'Dr. Mittens'
2   1           2       'Doc. Woofer'
3   2           3       'Name of Subject'
4   3           4       'Post 1'
5   3           4       'Post 2'
6   2           3       'Name of another Subject'
```

I might be wrong - correct me if you can.

Comment: I wouldn't create such a structure in MySQL because it still lacks recursive queries. So querying that will be really difficult.

Comment: Good point, I'm working on SQL Server, not MySQL. Recursive queries work there well. But in the end it depends how user wants to query data. Having 4 different tables might be better approach.

Comment: Hey, thanks - I'm not sure how should I use recursive queries, but your solution doesn't seem to fit exactly hat we need, because I think in the future we'll have fields that don't apply for all types of rows, e.g. 'icon_url' would only be for `profs` but not `sprofs`,`subjects` or `posts`. Also your solution will make a very big table, which would make searching through it slower (correct me if I'm wrong, I'm pretty new to this)

Comment: Its a long discussion if you need to use Mongo here. Mongo is good for hierarchical data. What is going to be the size of your dataset? Do you perform complex join with your tables? Your database is mainly read or write heavy?

Comment: I would not use this design in a SQL database, regardless of which one or whether it supports recursive queries.